# Gemfile: Make sure some gems are available on the machine, but don't need to be loaded for the project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, yard

I didn't work with RoR for 2-3 years, but now I'm back in business, and I really like the `bundle` command. But I'm a bit unsure how to make sure my fellow developers have all gems installed that **are not strictly part of the Rails application**.

For example, we use YARD for documentation. YARD doesn't have anything to do with the Rails project we are working on, so I'm not sure whether I should add it to its Gemfile. On the other hand, this is the only way to make sure every developer has it installed automatically.

And if I add it to Gemfile, how exactly should I do it? In the `:development` group, so it doesn't get loaded for production? But strictly speaking, it also shouldn't be loaded in development, it **simply just be installed** so it can be used manually.

So how should I add it? Thanks, guys, for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:development` group in the Gemfile is exactly the right place for this. There are nice commands that mean users can install only specific groups they need. See [the docs for more information on groups with Bundler](http://gembundler.com/groups.html).

[You can look at the Rails project's Gemfile itself](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/Gemfile#L32-40) to note that they have a group called `:doc` which they use to the same effect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this good explanation. Thank God the Gemfile is the right place! ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you feel the :development scope in your App Gemfile is not the right place, you could go for a shared Gemfile that exists just for this purpose. (That is, set up a repository somewhere just containing this Gemfile, run bundle install on it and the gems will be installed locally).

Comment: So you say it's absolutely legitimate to put it into the :development group?